# Taking away a positive number from a negative - Two's Complement

Tags: binary, addition, subtraction, twos-complement

Using two's complement form I need to with 8 bits perform the following:

- Subtract 45 from -20.

Another way that you could ask this would be saying "take 45 away from -20 or '-20 - 45'" or different again would be "-20 + -45".

My  thinking is that I should get the twos complement of -20 (11101100) and then add it to the twos complement of -45 (11010011) or vice versa. That would give me:

```
  1110 1100
  1101 0011
= 1111 1111
```

This is obviously not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is with the second MSB - you've added 1+1 to be 1, where in fact + is basically a XOR operation, so 1+1 should have been 0, and then you carry the 1.

`-20 + -45` is the correct way to calculate it and it should be:

```
  1
  1110 1100
  1101 0011 
  ---------
= 1011 1111
```

Basically, for the MSB you got `1+1+1` which is equivalent to `0+1` (or `1+0`), which of course is `1`.

And thus you got `10111111` which is `-65` in decimal:

```
-2^7 + 2^5 +2 ^4 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0
= -128 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1
= -65
```

Comment: You're dead right and now I feel stupid! A case of functional fixedness I imagine. Thanks!